# Get current task ID in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

How can I find out what tasks are executing which iterations of a
forall loop?

For example, I'd like to get a feel for how the different DynamicIters behave,

```
use DynamicIters;
var r = 1..1000;
var A: [r] int;

forall i in adaptive(r) {
       A[i] = ???;
}
```

I can use `here.id` to discover what locale a forall loop has put an
iteration on, but I don't know how to "see" what task within the
locale each iteration was assigned to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapel's design intentionally avoids supporting a standard language-level way to query a task's ID because we didn't want it to impose any particular numbering or overheads that might be required to maintain the feature across distinct underlying runtime/OS/hardware choices.  When writing **`coforall`** loops, a standard trick for creating virtual task IDs is to do something like this:

```
coforall (i, tid) in zip(myIter(), 0..) do
```

Since each iteration of the loop executes as a separate task, `tid` will uniquely number each of them starting at `0`.  But as you're noting, since task creation is abstracted away into iterators when using **`forall`** loops, they don't have a straightforward equivalent -- you'd typically need to modify the task-parallel constructs in the parallel iterators that are driving the loop in order to reason about what tasks are being created and what they are doing.

In the specific case of the **`DynamicIters`** module that you're curious about, there is a **`config`** param named `debugDynamicIters` that supports printing information about what's going on, so if you compile your program with `-sdebugDynamicIters=true`, you'll get some sense of what's going on with the tasks.  And of course, you can also modify the iterators themselves ( located in `$CHPL_HOME/modules/standard/DynamicIters.chpl` ) to add additional debug printing.

It is possible to go outside of the language and access the task IDs that the runtime uses, though there's no guarantee that this will be portable across different runtime tasking options ( e.g., qthreads, fifo, massivethreads ) nor that it will continue to work across future versions of Chapel.  For example, in Chapel 1.15.0, the following code works:

```
extern proc chpl_task_getId(): chpl_taskID_t;

forall i in adaptive(r) do
  writeln("task ", chpl_task_getId(), " owns iter ", i);
```

The type **`chpl_taskID_t`** is an opaque type that's internal to the implementation, so it can be printed out, but there's no guarantee that it will have any given type across tasking options or utilize any specific set of values.

Comment: the interaction of an open-ended iterator with a close-ended iterator inside the `zip( .., .. )` augmentation is a lovely syntax feature. Is it having a zero-overhead, as having been solved / mapped in compile-( front-end + back-end )-time, or does it also incur any execution time overhead?

Comment: Thanks!  It should effectively have zero overhead if we're doing our job correctly.  We also intend to add the ability for users to create their own open-ended iterators that would behave similarly (e.g., "read from my data file as long as is necessary..."), though that is unfortunately not yet supported.  For this reason, unbounded ranges are more of a special case in the language than ideal, at present.

Comment: **Zero-overhead syntax features are nothing less than cardinal properties for parallel languages**. Is it possible to **measure that** rigorously? How does Chapel guarantee system-wide coherent timers on deployment hardware to be able to indeed { clock | timestamp }-the-real-{-overheads | -latencies } upon entering parallel and just concurrent sections of `{ coforall | forall | begin }` & other { scheduling | execution } syntax-features? **Do indeed both the `Timer` instance & `getCurrentTime( TimeUnit.microseconds )` hold system-wide robust clock-coherence down to `TimeUnit.microseconds`?**

Comment: Chapel can't keep clocks and times any more coherent than the underlying system does---that is, we don't implement time natively in Chapel; instead we rely on the underlying system's implementation.  Note that Chapel was designed to be a parallel, concurrent, and distributed language, but not necessarily a real-time one (though we've asked at times whether that would be an interesting research question / extension).

Comment: Good morning to Seattle. The motivation of the Chapel is clear & the R/T sort of aspects was not raised. Trouble with state-full features, nevertheless, is not possible to be just left on hardware per-se. As I have asked in email, this relates to more syntax-elements -- to the `Timer` instances ( out of question ), even more importantly to the ( distributed ) sources of randomness, similarly to FSA-based `ZeroMQ.socket` instances. So there is a strong importance of how the Chapel distributes these instances or mediates a remote-code access ( from a far-end Locality to non-local instances ).

Comment: A declaration like: `var t: Timer` creates a single timer object on a single locale and all actions on that variable related to measuring time should be executed on that locale such that there is no system-wide aspect to its behavior nor coherence concern (that I can see).  If other locales access the Timer object, they will be doing remote reads/writes to the object.  Mediation of remote access is done through the language's memory consistency model (documented in the spec).  I'm not familiar enough with ZeroMQ to comment on it.  I'm about a month behind on email due to CHIUW, with apologies.

Comment: All this is clear, Brad. The point is how to time-stamp and measure right the very cost of the task distribution ( a tooling for the realistic, in-vivo measurements of the implementation overheads for the respective language { parallel | distributed } code-execution syntax-constructors' features once deployed ), between the points of being still on the initial single locale & the remote ones, where the code-execution has been wide-spread and continues to run. These efforts were mentioned as a professional parallel languages benchmarking initiative on ACCU 2017, weren't they? G/L for CHIUW 2017

Comment: When we report timings, we typically measure them from a single locale. For example, to time a forall loop that targets multiple locales, we start the timer, fire the forall loop, wait for it to complete, and check the timer. In other cases we might fire off remote tasks using coforall+on, start a timer on each locale, compute, then stop and read each timer.  We tend not to start a timer on one locale and reason about it on another. Doing so today would require accessing some sort of system-coherent timer external to Chapel. In HPC ping-pong round-trips tend to be used for similar reasons.

Comment: Exactly. But not doing this ( not recording ( hiding or ignoring ) the actual durations of non-local task dispatches + data marshalling ) effectively avoids all rigorous system-design decisions to be based on measuring the really accrued costs of distribution / collection overheads and thus **avoids the fair & correct computation of the "Point of Diminishing Returns" in the Amdahl Law's sense**, where exactly these overheads must be systematically included, if the formula ought to remain fair and scientifically correct & coherent with the real progress of the process scheduling and execution.

Comment: At this point, StackOverflow started chastising me along the lines of "This looks like a conversation, maybe you should take it elsewhere" so I've moved my response to email.